# Is there a better solution to join the same dataset to get the distinct count of a dimension used for aggregation?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to do an aggregation on certain measures, but i also have to say how much distinct values i have for a dimension, which i use for aggregation. I can solve the problem using two sub-selects, but performance is not the best. Is there any way to solve this using one select only? Any solution with better performance is welcomed.

test data i have:

```
create table test
(
dim1 varchar(50),
dim2 varchar(50),
measure1 numeric,
measure2 numeric
)

insert into test
select 'a','sas',120,1700
union all
select 'b','pop',150,150,
union all
select 'c','sas',132,150,
union all
select 'c','sas',150,100
```

sql i have:

```
select x.dim1,
       x.dim2,
       y.count_dim2
       x.measure1,
       x.measure2 
 from
(
select
dim1,
dim2,
sum(measure1) measure1,
sum(measure2) measure2 
from test
group by dim1, dim2
) x,
(
select
x.dim1,
count(distinct dim2) as count_dim2
from test
group by dim1
) y
where x.dim1 = y.dim1
```

is there any way to solve the above using 1 select only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do a *Group Count* on the result of the aggregation:

```
SELECT
   dim1,
   dim2,
   COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY dim1),
   SUM(measure1) measure1,
   SUM(measure2) measure2 
FROM test
GROUP BY dim1, dim2
```